# Elastic seacrh query for dict in python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am forming query for a dict property (python).
dict is :

```
{src: {u'zone_uuid': [u'Finance'], u'address_uuid':
[u'70933214-0d12-407c-9fb1-0a20870dd1bf'], u'zone': [u'Finance'],
u'address': ["[u'host-11', u'1.1.1.11']"]}}
```

query is:

```
{"query": {"bool": {"must":[{"query_string": {"query":
"src.address._lowercase:/.*host-11.*/","analyze_wildcard": "true"}}]}}}
```

This works fine.

But if I make query like this on dict element (src in this case) instead of its property, it does not work.

```
{"query": {"bool": {"must":[{"query_string": {"query":
"**src._lowercase:/.*host-11.***/","analyze_wildcard": "true"}}]}}}
```

How can I search directly on dict (in this case src)?